# How to create persist function on checkbox if data is present

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have seen many checkbox examples, but not this one.

I need a checkbox to remain checked if data is present in specific `<input>` fields. So it would need to be something that is constantly checking field status.

Basic checkbox:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" unchecked onclick="shipping()"/>
```

It calls a function that removes a `<div>` and adds a shipping info page.  There is a back button there that will remove shipping page and add orig.  If they entered shipping data I want that checkbox to be checked. Now if they click it again, the data they entered on the shipping page would disappear.  And process can be repeated.

This is a PHP page so I am comfortable using javascript, jQuery or PHP.  Just looking for the most reliable way.

Comment: Are you saying that the user can check or uncheck the checkbox as they please if there is no content in a specified text `<input>` but if there is content in the specified `<input>` then the checkbox must remain checked?

Comment: Yes, so form starts, box is unchecked.  They check it and that takes them to area to add dif shipping info. When they click back BTN shipping area disappears.  But the checkbox should now be checked.  If they click it again it would unCheck and delete all of that info.  I will update post to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is the way to go because PHP can't react to what's happening in the browser.  I would register an `onchange` event handler to the input that drives the checkbox. When the input is altered (ie when the handler is triggered):

1. Read the value, and if it is empty then...
2. Enable the checkbox.
3. Else, disable the checkbox and set it as checked

This should prevent a user of the UI from unchecking the box while there is content in the input